# How can I use the combinations object from itertools to find every arrangement of a string that I would input?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

My code

```
from itertools import permutations

original = input('What word would you like to unscramble?: ')

notSoOriginal = permutations(original)

print(notSoOriginal)
```

Whenever I input a word for the "original" variable, it returns

```
<itertools.permutations object at 0x02DCC6C0>
```

What would I change here in order to take the input string for "original" and have it print all the possible rearrangements of the characters? I'm also running Python 3.3 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Aside: if you want every "rearrangement", don't you want `permutations`, not `combinations`?

Comment: @DSM You're right, I changed it, and it still returned the same thing, but yes I should've used permutations instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for:

```
print([''.join(tup) for tup in permutations(original)])
```

`permutations` returns an iterator (not a list) of tuples containing all the permutations of `original` (e.g. `('t', 'e', 'n'), ('t', 'n', 'e'), ...`). So you need to iterate over the iterator, and join each tuple in to a string.

Answer (score 1):

DSM (in the comments) is right that you want [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) rather than [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

As to your reported problem - like everything else in the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module, `permutations` and `combinations` return [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators). So, you can either iterate over the result:

```
for permuted in permutations(original):
    print(permuted)
```

... or convert it to a list:

```
print(list(permutations(original)))
```